# databinding in recyclerView

Tags: android, realm, android-databinding

I want to use `DataBinding` at my simple project. into my `Recyclerview` Adapter layout(**rv_color_item.xml**) item according android wiki i write this code:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="shahramColor"
            type="com.groot.rang.model.ShahramColor"/>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context="com.groot.rang.PagerColorActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:cardCornerRadius="18dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imvItemColor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@{shahramColor.color}" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Now in my adapter in onBindViewHolder method i write these codes:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
ShahramColor color = colors.get(position);
if (holder instanceof ColorViewHolder) {
    ((ColorViewHolder) holder).binding.setShahramColor(color);
```

But when i want to run project in emulator I got this error:

```
 Error:(10, 34) error: cannot find symbol class RvColorItemBinding
```

When I removed

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="shahramColor"
        type="com.groot.rang.model.ShahramColor"/>
</data>
```

and

```
android:background="@{shahramColor.color}"
```

I can run app in emulator and no Error is appear and everything is work correctly.why i got error?

This is my pojo class:

```
public class ShahramColor extends RealmObject implements Serializable{

    private String refrenceColor;
    private String color;
    ... setter and getter
```

*********************Edit ******************

I have added this to gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {...
```

Comment: @VishvaDave I do rebuild and invalideate caches and restarted but nothing is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapter class:

```
public class ColorsRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ColorsRecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<ShahramColor> data;


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        private final ViewDataBinding binding;

        public MyViewHolder(ViewDataBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }

        public void bind(Object obj) {
            binding.setVariable(BR.obj, obj);
            binding.executePendingBindings();
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public ColorsRecyclerViewAdapter(List<ShahramColor> myDataset) {
        data = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.rv_color_item, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        return new MyViewHolder(binding);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ShahramColor colors = data.get(position);
        holder.bind(colors);

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

}
```

Model class :

```
import android.databinding.BaseObservable;
import android.databinding.Bindable;

public class TemperatureData extends BaseObservable {

    private String location;

    private String celsius;

    private String url;

    public TemperatureData(String location, String celsius, String url) {
        this.location = location;
        this.celsius = celsius;
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getCelsius() {
        return celsius;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }


    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.location);
    }

    public void setCelsius(String celsius) {
        this.celsius = celsius;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.celsius);
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
        notifyPropertyChanged(BR.url);
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont think the problem isfor my adapter: http://codepad.org/cmipjsqY  without `android:background="@{shahramColor.color}"` and `<data>
    <variable
        name="shahramColor"
        type="com.groot.rang.model.ShahramColor"/>
</data>` databinding worked.

Comment: without that i use like this:`((ColorViewHolder) holder).binding.imvItemColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color.getColor())); in onBindViewHolder method

Comment: `BR` is known but obj is cannot resolve symbole obj`?

Comment: @sayreskabir change obj to shahramColor. this is variable name defined in xml.

Comment: @sayreskabir if you can change in xml shahramColor to obj then this could be more easier for you. if possible

Comment: i got this error `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
  ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:background' with parameter type java.lang.String on android.widget.ImageView.
  file:D:\Tutorial\Android\project\Groot-Dev\Rang\app\src\main\res\layout\rv_color_item.xml
  loc:32:38 - 32:55
  ****\ data binding error ****` @vishvadave

Comment: @sayreskabir sorry model class also need to be updated i am adding. change it accordingly yours.

Comment: I cannot extends BaseObservable because i am using realm and i have to extend from RealmObject. @vishvadave

Comment: @sayreskabir then i can't help. sorry :)

Comment: @sayreskabir wait i have one link https://medium.com/@Zhuinden/realm-1-2-0-android-data-binding-1dc06822287f

Comment: which efforts?ops I donot know about these efforts.please send again :-)

Comment: Happy to help :) Happy coding :)